# Python syntaxErrors

Tags: python, syntax-error

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong in the syntax.
I'm trying to execute a script and its returning me a lot of errors, most of them in `try-exception`(example 1,2,3) and something wrong on example 4...
Does anyone see an issue here?

Example 1:

```
def post(self, data):
        post_data = json.dumps(data)
        if VERBOSE:
            sys.stderr.write("\nDEBUG: POST data: %r\n" % post_data)
        try:
            # Watch out: we must provide the verify keyword to every individual request call!
            # Else it will be overwritten by the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE env variable
            raw_response = self._session.post(self.base_url,
                                              data=post_data,
                                              verify=self._session.verify)
        except () if DEBUG else Exception, exc:
            sys.stderr.write("ERROR: %s\n" % exc)
            raise SkipMBean(exc)

        return validate_response(raw_response)
```

Example 2:

```
def _get_queries(do_search, inst, itemspec, title, path, mbean):
    if not do_search:
        return [(mbean + "/" + path, title, itemspec)]

    try:
        value = fetch_var(inst, "search", mbean)
    except () if DEBUG else SkipMBean:
        return []

    try:
        paths = make_item_list((), value, "")[0][1]
    except IndexError:
        return []

    return [("%s/%s" % (urllib2.quote(mbean_exp), path), path, itemspec) for mbean_exp in paths]
```

Example 3:

```
def _process_queries(inst, queries):
    for mbean_path, title, itemspec in queries:
        try:
            for item, out_title, value in fetch_metric(inst, mbean_path, title, itemspec):
                yield item, out_title, value
        except (IOError, socket.timeout):
            raise SkipInstance()
        except SkipMBean:
            continue
        except () if DEBUG else Exception:
            continue
```

Example 4:

```
def generate_values(inst, var_list):
    for var in var_list:
        mbean, path, title, itemspec, do_search = var[:5]
        value_type = var[5] if len(var) >= 6 else None

        queries = _get_queries(do_search, inst, itemspec, title, path, mbean)

        for item, title, value in _process_queries(inst, queries):
            if value_type:
                yield item, title, value, value_type
            else:
                yield item, title, value
```

This is one of the errors it send out, for example 1:

```
File "jolokia_metrics", line 342
    except () if DEBUG else Exception, exc:
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: "A lot of errors" like what?

Comment: Also, could you please edit the code so it's more legible

Answer (score 0):

```
except () if DEBUG else Exception, exc: 
except () if DEBUG else SkipMBean:
except () if DEBUG else Exception:
```

This syntax is not supported in newer versions of Python.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html